# Truncating text instead of wrapping in a view

Tags: 7, theming

I have a view that displays an image, title, star rating and user name of a custom content-type I have created in a grid. When  I have a very long title it messes up the layout of the view and makes it look bad as you can see in the below image:
[image]

Is there a way I can have long titles like the one below display with only one line and then truncate the rest with an ellipsis.  I.E. I would like the first content to have a title of "Very Long title for..." instead of "Very Long title for this project that will wrap to the next line".  This doesn't seem possible to do from the site builder, is there a module that might allow you to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) to do this:

In the `Node : Title` field, there is a setting to limit the number of characters labeled `Trim this field to a maximum length`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible with Drupal 7 Views.

Comment: Please say MotoTribe's Answer for more information.

Answer (score 4):

yes, it is, it's under "rewrite results".

[image]

But please mark vr3690's answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jquery.motrim.js](https://github.com/michaelocana/motrim). It will truncate the long text by word and the `div.wrapper` width so it won't cut the long text by number of characters.